# Pepper: retrieving a memory variable in web app

Tags: javascript, pepper

I'm programming an app for the Aldebaran's Pepper robot. I'm using Choregraphe and I made a web app to display in robots tablet. I am trying to pass on a variable from Pepper's behavior to the web app javascript.

My idea was to insert a key, data pair in Pepper's memory with a default insertData box, and then to load the app and retrieve it from memory there. The javascript code would look something like this.

```
var session = new QiSession();
var memory;
session.service("ALMemory").then(function(m) {    
    memory = m;});
var data = memory.getData('key')
```

I think it is close to working, but it's not quite there yet. Any ideas?

What is in general the best way to pass a variable to javascript?

Kind regards,

(This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45876099/pepper-pass-variable-from-python-to-web-js/46176329#46176329), but my approach is different and I was asked to create a new one.)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure everything is done as callbacks, as each NAOqi function gives you futures.

See doc [here](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/dev/js/index.html).

```
QiSession(function(session) {
    session.service("ALMemory").then(function(m) { 
        m.getData('key').then(function(data) {
            // do something with the data!
        }, console.log);
    },console.log);
},console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow docs [here](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/dev/js/index.html#compatibility-between-signals-and-almemory).

1.Start a session.

2.Connect to **ALMemory** service

```
QiSession(function (session) {
      console.log("connected!");
      session.service("ALMemory").then(function (memory) {
        memory.subscriber("event-key").then(function(subscriber){
          subscriber.signal.connect(function(data){
            // use the data here
        });
        });
      }, function (error) {
        console.log("An error occurred:", error);
      });
    }, function () {
      console.log("disconnected");
    });
```